# How to add particular element of dict

Tags: python, dictionary, python-3.6, keyerror

```
sleeps=[{"summaryId ": "x209bf59-59b0c5a8-585c ", 
         "validation ": "AUTO_TENTATIVE ", 
         "durationInSeconds ": 22620, 
         "startTimeInSeconds ": 1504757160, 
         "awakeDurationInSeconds ": 900, 
         "startTimeOffsetInSeconds ": -14400, 
         "deepSleepDurationInSeconds ": 8160, 
         "lightSleepDurationInSeconds ": 13560},
        {"summaryId ": "x209bf59-59b0c5a8-23a0 ", 
         "validation ": "AUTO_TENTATIVE ",
         "durationInSeconds ": 9120, 
         "startTimeInSeconds ": 1504757160,
         "awakeDurationInSeconds ": 300, 
         "startTimeOffsetInSeconds ": -14400, 
         "deepSleepDurationInSeconds ": 1680, 
         "lightSleepDurationInSeconds ": 7140}
       ]

res = sum([x["durationInSeconds"] for x in sleeps]) 
print(res)
```

This is throwing a `Keyerror`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The key you want to modify has a redundant space in your dict definition

```
"durationInSeconds "
                  ^
```

Answer (score 0):

Hashing and comparisons take whitespaces into account. Probably easier to spot the difference if they are printed next to each other:

```
"durationInSeconds "
"durationInSeconds"
```

The first one has a trailing whitespace.

```
>>> hash(s1) == hash(s2)
False
>>> s1 == s2
False
```

So they are in no respect equal to each other which also explains the `KeyError`. To fix it you either need to remove the trailing whitespace in the dictionary, or look up the key with the trailing whitespace. For example:

```
>>> res = sum([x["durationInSeconds "] for x in sleeps]) 
>>> print(res)
31740
```